# Script that resizes div based on background-image size -- Not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, browser

I have this script that resizes the height of a div, based on the height of the background image that is set for it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = $('#header').css('background-image').replace('url(', '').replace(')', '').replace("'", '').replace('"', '');
    var bgImg = $('<img />');
    bgImg.hide();
    bgImg.bind('load', function()
    {
        var height = $(this).height();
        $("#content").css("margin-top",height+"px");
        $("#header").css("min-height",height+"px");
    });
    $('#header').append(bgImg);
    bgImg.attr('src', url);
});
```

For some reason, it works just fine in both Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox. I've checked the console in FF to see if there are any errors, but there are none. Not sure if there is something here incompatible with FF or some weird FF thing that I'm not familiar with. Any comments appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `.replace("'", '')` and `.replace('"', '')` only replace the FIRST quote.

Then, you can use regular expressions with the `g` (global) flag: `.replace(/'/g, '')` and `.replace(/"/g, '')`. Or even better, join them all:

```
.replace(/url\(|\)|'|"/g, '');
```